# Actions on Google Internationalization

Tags: internationalization, actions-on-google, api-ai

Last week during the  Google I/O '17, Google annonced that Google Assistant will soon be available in other countries (like France, Germany, Japan...)
I'm a french developer and I want to develop a new Action for Google Assistant.

Currently it's only possible to do it in English but does somebody know if an internationalization system will be available or if I will have to develop a copy of my current English agent and translate it on french when Google Assistant will be available for french people ?

If an internationalization system is created, will it be available only on API.ai, only on Actions SDK or on both ?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Google Assistant is currently deploy to French user (29/05/2017), an internationalization system is now really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update after 10/04 Google conference]

Api.ai now supports multi-language agents:
https://api.ai/docs/multi-language

And Actions on Google also supports multi language: in the App Information screen, you can use the arrow near "English" and click on "Add language".

More supported languages are coming soon...